# Issue while generating NFT metadata

Tags: smart-contracts, nft, blockchain, metadata

I have a problem for the generation of my metadata:
[image: null metadata]

https://ghostnet.tzkt.io/KT19FWtPSqybX52WaLVAD3xbWyHiRqNupD9Q/tokens/14/metadata

This is how I generate my metadata in my code:

```
const metadata = await client.store({
                date: new Date().toISOString(),
                name: name,
                description: description,
                decimals: 0,
                symbol: symbol,
                image: new File(
                    [filesContent[0].content],
                    filesContent[0].name,
                    { type: "image/" + filesContent[0].name.split(".")[1] }
                ),
                minter: walletAddress,
                rights: "No License / All Rights Reserved",
                creators: walletAddress,
                displayUri: new File(
                    [filesContent[0].content],
                    filesContent[0].name,
                    { type: "image/" + filesContent[0].name.split(".")[1] }
                ),
                artifactUri: new File(
                    [filesContent[0].content],
                    filesContent[0].name,
                    { type: "image/" + filesContent[0].name.split(".")[1] }
                ),
                thumbnailUri: new File(
                    [filesContent[0].content],
                    filesContent[0].name,
                    { type: "image/" + filesContent[0].name.split(".")[1] }
                ),
                contract_link: contract_link,

            });
dispatch(mintNFT({Tezos, amount, metadata: (metadata.url)}))
```

my smart contract: https://legacy.smartpy.io/ide?cid=QmPF25WTTnBvapzktXrQ9JeKPZsjMTFs7Br2rJdUTLyK3v&k=a1b8793016011b3decbb

I would like to know where is my mistake, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see it's now working.

It may take quite some time for IPFS nodes to synchronize and/or explorer to gather them.

I suggest you to always test with tzcomet, that gives more info: https://tzcomet.io/#/token/KT19FWtPSqybX52WaLVAD3xbWyHiRqNupD9Q/13%3Fexplorer-input%3DKT19FWtPSqybX52WaLVAD3xbWyHiRqNupD9Q